# Including slick2d or slick-util in maven build?

Tags: java, slick

I'm converting a project to lwjgl and trying to use slick-util as well. There's no slick-util maven repo anywhere (nor slick2d itself anymore). I've included local dependancies before using

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.newdawn</groupId>
        <artifactId>slick</artifactId>
        <version>237</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/slick-util.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

The maven package process runs without issue, but when I try to run the jar, it errors out with a `ClassNotFoundException`. There's no mention of slick-util in the manifest and I can't find out how to make my game load that jar properly.

Side question: how do I ensure when I distribute my applications, the game properly installs these libraries?

Comment: You should check this project:
https://github.com/nguillaumin/slick2d-maven

Answer (score 0):

Your seem to be missing the dependency for slick at runtime. Hard to tell without knowing Class was not found. Is it a class from the slick dependency?
Using scope compile instead of system should fix it.